# SP 2010: Scopes not updated for Web Applications using Claims BAsed Authentication

Tags: administration, infrastructure, search-scope, search-results

I have configured a web application with Claims Based Authentication because it needs to use FBA. I've created a search scope in the central admin to query all documents in my web app: contentclass = STS_List_DocumentLibrary

Looking at the Search Administrator level my scope is not getting updated: 0 items
looking on one of the sites in my Web App to the scope settings, I see the correct number of items

When I use the search core results web part based on this scope it's of course not returning any items.
When I use the enterprise search site I can search and find items (member of the scope)

Anyone some ideas how to resolve this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Search will use your default zone.  Default zone should be configured for NTLM.  So if you are using claims be sure that NTLM is checked as well as FBA.

This will trigger the claims logon page to select the authentication type.  You will either have to customize the page to make it transparent, or extend your WebApp to a new zone with just FBA enabled.